# set of dictionaries in list of dictionarys

Tags: python, dictionary, set

trying to find a set of dictionaries in a list.

Say I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
rm_dict = [{'name':'rick','subject':'adventure time mortttty buugh','body':['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!', 'morty get over here!']},
 {'name':'rick','subject':'adventure time mortttty buugh','body':['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!', 'morty get over here!']},
 {'name':'morty','subject':'re:adventure time mortttty buugh','body':['youre drunk rick!', 'I'm going to get mom', 'you always do this']}]
```

trying just `set`, I get an error.

```
set(rm_dict)
```

I take the body of the message/email, because that's what I'll use to define as unique, and create a list of the body of all of the emails, and then I will do a generator for `set(tuple())` etc..

```
list_of_body = [x['body'] for x in rm_dict]
>>[['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!'],
  ['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!'],
  ['youre drunk rick!']]

[list(item) for item in set(tuple(row) for row in list_of_body)]
>>[['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!'], ['youre drunk rick!']]
```

This succeeds in getting me the unique bodies from the `list_of_body`, but I want the *whole* dictionary from the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is telling you something important: neither a dictionary or a list is hashable, and so cannot be used as a member of set.  One way to work around that is to use the `str` that is the 0th element of the email body in your data.

You can "uniqify" your list based on one of its keys with a list comprehension:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [i for i in rm_dict if i['body'][0] not in seen and not seen.add(i['body'][0])]
[{'name': 'rick',
  'subject': 'adventure time mortttty buugh',
  'body': ['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!']},
 {'name': 'morty',
  'subject': 're:adventure time mortttty buugh',
  'body': ['youre drunk rick!']}]
```

Here's another form, without the comprehension:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> emails = []
>>> for i in rm_dict:
...     body = i['body'][0]
...     if body not in seen:
...         emails.append(i)
...         seen.add(body)
...         

>>> emails
[{'name': 'rick',
  'subject': 'adventure time mortttty buugh',
  'body': ['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!']},
 {'name': 'morty',
  'subject': 're:adventure time mortttty buugh',
  'body': ['youre drunk rick!']}]
```

Comment: My example was a bit wrong, as my `body` was a list of multiple strings, not just 1. So turning it into a tuple and using your code fixed it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set items have to be hashable, which dicts are not. You can use `pickle` to serialize all the dicts, then use `set` to obtain unique items, and finally deserialize them back to dicts:

```
import pickle
print(list(map(pickle.loads, set(map(pickle.dumps, rm_dict)))))
```

This outputs:

```
[{'name': 'morty', 'subject': 're:adventure time mortttty buugh', 'body': ['youre drunk rick!']}, {'name': 'rick', 'subject': 'adventure time mortttty buugh', 'body': ['wubba lubba dub dubbb motha f*&^%!']}]
```