# Set of Dictionary elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I want to create a set of dictionaries in python. I know how to make a list of dictionaries and convert it to set, but I want to add a dictionary to a set. Can anyone help me?
I got this error when I try below code:
"Exception has occurred: TypeError unhashable type: 'dict'"

```
C = set()
A = {'a':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
B = {'c':3, 'd':4, 2:5 }
C.add(A)
C.add(B)
```

Thanks

Comment: Its not directly possible since, as the error says, the `dict` type is not hashable. This is because they can be changed whilst in the `set`, which invalidates the reason for having a `set`. There is a `frozendict` somewhere in pypi.

Comment: As @quamrana said dict is unhashable so cannot be put in a set. I am curious about your statement `I know how to make a list of dictionaries and convert it to set` since converting a list of dicts to a set of dicts would have the same problem. can you show the code that you use to acheive this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717910/set-of-dictionaries-in-list-of-dictionarys

Comment: I don't know your application, but depending on the contents of the dictionary you might be able to convert it to a `JSON` string and store that. Then, of course, you would have to "reconstitute" the dictionary when needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the below:

```
C = set()
A = {'a':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
B = {'c':3, 'd':4, 2:5 }
```

You could do something like this to combine all the above into a single set. I will use an union operator '|' to achieve this.

```
{i for i in A.items()} | {i for i in B.items()}
```

This results to:

```
{('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 3), ('d', 4), (2, 5)}
```

** Extra Information **

If you knew from the start that dictionary B does not contain any of the keys found in dictionary A, you could do something like the below to combine the two dictionaries:

For example:

```
A = {'a':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
B = {'e':3, 'f':4, 2:5 }
from collections import Counter
C = Counter(A) + Counter(B)
```

C equates to the below:

```
Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 4, 2: 5})
```